# PDF quality significantly reduced when imported to Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images

I have a PDF figure that I want to place in my Word document. However the quality of the figure is significantly worse inside the Word file than individually as a PDF. How can I make sure the quality stays the same? Thank you!

Comment: If your Word Doc Page Size is the same as the PDF Doc Page Size , & you insert the PDF at a smaller Viewing Size , then naturally , there will be rescaling in the Word Doc which will make it look lossy. You should make sure your PDF Page is much smaller than the Word Doc Page , then insert at "Original Size" to get Exact Quality. Alternately , you should Extract the Image & Insert that Directly.

Comment: Hi, if the body of the PDF will fit between your header and page number, you can display the PDF at 100% and use the snapshot tool to grab just the body of the document, omitting any header/ footer on the PDF page, as well as left and right margins. You should then be able to paste the content into Word at approximately 100%, with less distortion.